# How to get selected text using the Firefox Add-On SDK?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to create a Firefox add-on using the online [Add-On SDK](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/).

I'm starting with something simple - I want to add a toolbar button that reads the current selected text.

The [documentation for the Selection](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.3/packages/addon-kit/docs/selection.html) object makes this looks simple enough:

```
var selection = require("selection");
if (selection.text)
  console.log(selection.text);
```

This doesn't seem to work for me, I just get `null`.

Here's my complete code:

```
var selection = require("selection");

require("widget").Widget({
    id: "widgetID1",
    label: "Test Mozilla Widget",
    contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
    onClick: function(event) {
        console.log('selection.text = ' + selection.text);
    }
});
```

I've also tried to create the `selection` object inside the `onClick` even, with the same effect.
I am able to use the [`select`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.3/packages/addon-kit/docs/selection.html#select) event to get notified on new selections, so I guess I can use that instead (and keep the value), but I wonder why the above code isn't working... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Wladimir - Are you sure that was the SDK? As far as I can tell, the SDK is installed locally. The site I used is titled "Add-on Builder"... They look like two different things in https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder (though, the API is hopefully the same)

Comment: It doesn't matter - the builder is merely a web tool to "compile" add-ons with the SDK. Whether you use a local SDK install or the builder, it is the same API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `selection` variable as defined will only have the selected text as long as it is in focus. Clicking on the widget icon takes focus away from the selected text, so it sees no text selected.

Thats why it works when used inside the listener function.

To confirm this, I tried logging its value when a toolbar button is pressed (using the [toolbarbutton module](https://github.com/voldsoftware/toolbarbutton-jplib)), and it works. Pressing a toolbar button (presumably) does not steal focus.

Here's the code, [and you can test it online too](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1030906/latest/):

```
var selection = require("selection");

var tbb = require("toolbarbutton").ToolbarButton({
    id: "test",
    label: "test",
    image: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
    onCommand: function(event) {
      console.log('selection = ' + JSON.stringify(selection)); // works!
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I added the code to the answer, hope you don't mind. It interesting - the Toolbar Button also reads the selection from the url text box, which is a little weird. I think I'll stay with the selection event (as in my answer), as it gives me the best results with no regard to focus. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. I experimented a bit with this, and my first answer was was going to be using the selection event. But then I discovered the focus problem, which was interesting.

Comment: your online test is gone

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using the `select` event:

```
var selection = require("selection");

var selectedText = '';

function selectionChanged(event){
    //todo: check for selection.isContiguous
    selectedText = selection.text;
}

selection.on('select', selectionChanged);

require("widget").Widget({
    id: "widgetID1",
    label: "Test Mozilla Widget",
    contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
    onClick: function(event) {
        console.log('Selection: ' + selectedText);
    }
});
```